# Second Monitor "Input Not Supported"

Tags: multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics

I have two identical monitors (new Acer s211hl) with a native resolution of 1920x1080. When enabling dual monitor support in Windows 7, the primary monitor works as expected, but the second monitor says, "Input not Supported" and fails to display anything.

If I change the resolution of the second monitor to 1440x900, it works as expected. Likewise, if I set it to 1920x1080 with a refresh rate of 30hz, the monitor displays video. However, neither of these are solutions, because the output looks very blurry, and the content is stretched.

I am using the following hardware:

- Monitors: Acer s211hl
- Motherboard: Asus F1A75M-Pro
- CPU/GPU: AMD A8-3850 with integrated Radeon HD 6550D graphics

I suspect that there is probably an issue with the integrated graphics or motherboard not being able to output to two 1920x1080 monitors, but I am hoping for official confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting the monitors? If using DVI and HDMI, it should work, if one is VGA, it looks as if that resolution is not supported:

[Asus specifications for the motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_Socket_FM1/F1A75M_PRO/#specifications)

Comment: DVI+VGA. Where did you see that VGA doesn't support it? I see this in the graphics section: " Supports RGB with max. resolution 1920 x 1600 @ 60 Hz"

Comment: it was an assumption. Which connection are you using as the primary monitor? have you tried switching them, like forcing the vga monitor to be primary? Also might be worth verifying you have the most recent drivers for the IGP/motherboard.

Comment: DVI as primary. I have the newest drivers from the website. I ended up just buying an additional video card, so don't spend too much time debugging it anymore.